# PowerShell Foreach and the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I am trying to edit a script I found online. It was originally written to scan a single user account for chrome extensions. I want to change it to scan a list of computers and all user accounts on that computer. when it scans i get a error for the extension path.

CODE:

```
 foreach($computer in $computers){

    $User = Get-Content -Path "\\$computer\C$\Users"
    Get-ChildItem $User | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host Scanning $computer


        ##: The extensions folder is in local appdata 
        $extension_folders = Get-Content -Path "\\$computer\c$\users\$user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\"
        Get-ChildItem $extension_folders |ForEach-Object {

            ##: Get the version specific folder within this extension folder
            $version_folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($extension_folder.FullName)"

                ##: Loop through the version folders found
                foreach ($version_folder in $version_folders) {

                ##: The extension folder name is the app id in the Chrome web store
                $appid = $extension_folder.BaseName
```

Error:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 
'\\gms-404-01S\c$\users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User 
Data\Default\Extensions\' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\clarkj8\Desktop\Untitled4.ps1:26 char:30
```

It is not pulling the user variable like i had hoped. to complete the path needed for the extension_folder variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FULL CODE most of this is not mine

```
$folder = "\\SERVER\PowershellScans\ExtensionList\"
$hostnamestxt = "\\SERVER\PowershellScans\404.txt"
$computers = get-content “$hostnamestxt”


if(!(Test-Path $folder)){
    New-Item "\\gmsms01\PowershellScans\ExtensionList\list.txt" -type directory -force


}


Write-Host “Scanning for Extensions"



foreach($computer in $computers){

    $User = Get-Content -Path "\\$computer\C$\Users"
    Get-ChildItem $User | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host Scanning $computer


        ##: The extensions folder is in local appdata 
        $extension_folders = Get-Content -Path "\\$computer\c$\users\$user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\"
        Get-ChildItem $extension_folders |ForEach-Object {

            ##: Get the version specific folder within this extension folder
            $version_folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($extension_folder.FullName)"

                ##: Loop through the version folders found
                foreach ($version_folder in $version_folders) {

                ##: The extension folder name is the app id in the Chrome web store
                $appid = $extension_folder.BaseName

                    ##: First check the manifest for a name
                    $name = ""
                    if( (Test-Path -Path "$($version_folder.FullName)\manifest.json") ) {
                        try {
                        $json = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$($version_folder.FullName)\manifest.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
                        $name = $json.name
                        } catch {
                        #$_
                        $name = ""
                        }
                    }

                ##: If we find _MSG_ in the manifest it's probably an app
                if( $name -like "*MSG*" ) {
                    ##: Sometimes the folder is en
                    if( Test-Path -Path "$($version_folder.FullName)\_locales\en\messages.json" ) {
                        try { 
                        $json = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$($version_folder.FullName)\_locales\en\messages.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
                        $name = $json.appName.message
                        ##: Try a lot of different ways to get the name
                            if(!$name) {
                            $name = $json.extName.message
                            }
                            if(!$name) {
                            $name = $json.extensionName.message
                            }
                            if(!$name) {
                             $name = $json.app_name.message
                            }
                             if(!$name) {
                             $name = $json.application_title.message
                            }
                         } catch { 
                         #$_
                        $name = ""
                        }
                     }
            ##: Sometimes the folder is en_US
            if( Test-Path -Path "$($version_folder.FullName)\_locales\en_US\messages.json" ) {
                try {
                    $json = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$($version_folder.FullName)\_locales\en_US\messages.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
                    $name = $json.appName.message
                    ##: Try a lot of different ways to get the name
                    if(!$name) {
                        $name = $json.extName.message
                    }
                    if(!$name) {
                        $name = $json.extensionName.message
                    }
                    if(!$name) {
                        $name = $json.app_name.message
                    }
                    if(!$name) {
                        $name = $json.application_title.message
                    }
                } catch {
                    #$_
                    $name = ""
                }
            }
        }

        ##: If we can't get a name from the extension use the app id instead
        if( !$name ) {
            $name = "[$($appid)]"
        }

        ##: App id given on command line and this one matched it
        if( $ExtensionId -and ($appid -eq $ExtensionId) ) {
            if( $Remove ) {
                echo "Removing item: [$appid] at path: [$($extension_folder.FullName)]"
                if(!($WhatIf)) {
                    ##: Remove the extension folder
                    if (Test-Path -Path $extension_folder.FullName) { 
                        Remove-Item -Path $extension_folder.FullName -Recurse -Force            
                    }

                    ##: Remove the extension registry key
                    if (Test-Path -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs\Default\extensions.settings") {
                        if( Get-ItemProperty -Name "$appid" -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs\Default\extensions.settings" ) {
                            Remove-ItemProperty -Name "$appid" -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs\Default\extensions.settings"
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ##: Dump to a file
                echo "Appending: [$name ($($version_folder)) - $appid] to audit file: [$auditfilepath]"
                if(!($WhatIf)) {
                    echo "$name ($($version_folder)) - $appid" | Out-File -Append $auditfilepath
                }
                ##: Exit with a TRUE value if the given extension id was found
                $retval = $true
            }

        ##: App id given on command line and this did NOT match it
        } elseif( $ExtensionId -and ($appid -ne $ExtensionId) ) {
            ##: NOP
            #echo "Skipping: [$appid] output"
        ##: App id not given on command line
        } else {
            ##: Dump to audit file
            echo "Appending: [$name ($($version_folder)) - $appid] to audit file: [$auditfilepath]"
            if(!($WhatIf)) {
                echo "$name ($($version_folder)) - $appid" | Out-File -Append "\\gmsms01\PowershellScans\ExtensionList\list.txt"
            }
        }

    }

}
}
}
```

Comment: I think you want `$_` instead of `$user` in the line where the error is being thrown.

Comment: that seems to have done it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment above, replacing `$user` with `$_` in the line that is throwing the error will cause your loop to work the way you want.

Comment: It is now "Working" but seems to be scanning much more than just the extension folders. Any chance you can see what is causing that error? there is no error being displayed. but it is writing a lot more than it should be to the final file.

Comment: This is why you should thoroughly understand PowerShell and be able to analyze the script - this is a fairly "deep" script, and looks for a lot of information regarding extensions. "Execute" the script "by hand"; that way, you will see what it's doing and why, and can then modify it to reduce the amount of unwanted data produced.